# Retrieve or compute color of Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp

I need to find out what color is used on background of start menu or notification center in Windows 10. It's probably computed from current accent color but I don't how. Changing HSV of accent color does not work very well. Can someone help me? Or is this color stored somewhere in registry?

[image]

Comment: I believe the Start menu as well as the Action Center do use the accent color. Both windows are translucent, though, so that changes the final color, as it is composited with the color underneath them.

Comment: It's not just about transparency. It is disabled on the screenshot I've provided.

Comment: The start menu is using the Windows accent color (if configured to do so, otherwise it is black). In order to improve readability of the text, a small black (or white) transparent overlay is applied on top of it. You can easily reproduce this overlay by drawing a black transparent surface on top of the accent color.

Comment: Have you tried the [various accent color variants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType)?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find out what color is used on background of start menu or notification center

Changing the windows color is the correct way to change the background of strat menu or notification center. But you need to have  the option `Start,taskbar, and action center` checked as well when setting the color.

[image]